# How to import an exclamation point (or other operator) from Haskell module

Tags: haskell, import, module

Haskell has a [Data.Map](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html) module which includes, among other functions, a [`!` function](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#v%3a!).

```
fromList [(5,'a'), (3,'b')] ! 1    Error: element not in the map
fromList [(5,'a'), (3,'b')] ! 5 == 'a'
```

While I can import other functions from the Data.Map module into my code...

```
import Data.Map(Map, keys, fromList)
```

...the following does NOT work...

```
import Data.Map(Map, keys, fromList, !)
```

I get the following error:

```
parse error on input `!'
```

What is the correct syntax to import items like `!`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The correct answer is to wrap the function name (really, it's an *operator*: a special case of a function) in parentheses, like so...

```
import Data.Map(Map, keys, fromList, (!))
```